# How to align list elements left, right and centered

Tags: css, position, alignment

look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ugxNK/

I want that the first list element is in the left corner, the middle in the center and the right one in the right corner.

How could I do this dynamicly so for different screen sizes?

I only know to align them with margins.

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a width to the list items like this:

```
.panel li
{
    display: inline-block;
    width:33%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ugxNK/2/)**.

Comment: Thats good! But what about the margin about the left element. How can I change this without loosing the other positions?

Comment: You can specify your margin on the `<ul>`. See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ugxNK/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can use selectors like `first-child`, `last-child` and `nth-child(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to have them in percentages?

> .panel li { float: left; width: 40%; display: block; text-align: left }
>
> .panel li.center { width: 20%; text-align: left }
>
> .panel li.right { text-align: right }

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
.left { float:left }
.right { float:right }
ul{text-align:center; overflow:hidden}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ugxNK/4/